# Echo rows without numeric characters at the beginning of the row

Tags: php, database, replace, echo, numeric

I have some rows in the database, all start with numbers:

```
1 some text
2 another text 
13 more text
```

I use the command to show these rows

```
$title = "$chapter : {$row[0]}"
```

where $row[0] is any chosen row from the database of the above example.

What I need is to make the command shows the rows without the numbers that come at the beginning of each row.

I found some options like preg_replace('/^[0-9]+. +/', '', $string) - but I don't know how to implement them in the command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do

```
 $field = preg_replace('/^[0-9]+. +/', '', $row[0]);
 $title = $chapter ." : ".$field;
```